# datepicker not working in rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I am trying to implement a datepicker in my rails view.

My view is :-

```
    <%= f.label :start_date %>       
    <%= f.text_field :start_date,:id => "season_start_date"  %>
```

My application.html.erb :-

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>

 <%= javascript_include_tag     "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js",   

"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.min.js","application" %>
```

And my application.js file looks like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(ev){
    $("#season_start_date").click(function(){
      $('#season_start_date').datepicker();
   });
 });
```

And my gem file:-

```
gem "jquery_datepicker"
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was resolved when i removed all the javascript include tag contents except application.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

I guess because of the multiple js files it was getting confused and hence was throwing error no method 'datepicker.'

Answer (score 1):

You don't need launch datepicker on click do only :

```
$(document).ready(function(ev){
  $('#season_start_date').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Thanks shingara for the response .. but still I am not able to get the date

Comment: YEs it says Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

Comment: put your jquery file like jquery.js or jquery-1.7.2.js above or it should load before datepicker. you should maintain order of js.